# Unable to resolve AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"String types not allowed

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am new to android studio and building my first project.
The following error occurred:

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"String types not allowed (at \u0027android:textColor\u0027 with value \u0027\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.4.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1247,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":95714,"endColumn":61,"endOffset":95771}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I have no idea what caused the error. I didn't edit anything in the values.xml file. I just tried to change the background of linearlayout after which this error occurred.
On line 1247 there is just a closing tag: < /style>
Can someone please help me?
Thank you

Here is the link to the xml file: https://github.com/mehulverma/values5way/blob/xml/values.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved. I had specified the wrong colour in styles.xml file for a particular style. I removed the line and it worked. A rookie mistake I guess. Thanks for your help.